# python3.8 no such file or directory when trying to git commit to bitbucket on mac

Tags: python, git, macos, bitbucket

I am currently on a new mac with python 3.8.2 installed. I have a bitbucket repo I cloned down. When I modify a file and `git add` that works fine. But when I make a `git commit` I get this error message

```
env: python3.8: No such file or directory
```

My path env variable looks like this

```
PATH=/Users/rach/bin:/Users/rach/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

When I type whereis python3 I get

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

I cannot figure out why I can't make a git commit with python3 already installed and the location in the path

Comment: Do you have any git-hooks set up? (Does `ls .git/hooks` show anything?)

Comment: Ahh thank you! There was some things sneaked into the pre-commit under .git/hooks/pre-commit

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Since you're using `pre-commit`, you can uninstall hooks by:

```
pre-commit uninstall
```

To install them again, run:

```
pre-commit install
```

Comment: Just to add: If it says "no module named pre-commit", just do `pip install pre-commit` and do `pre-commit uninstall`.

Comment: Also to add to this, you can do an `ls .git/hooks/` then remove anything not needed like `rm .git/hooks/pre-commit` and others if you don't need those either.